# Is it possible to create namespaced environment variables in powershell? (like $custom:JSenv)

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I was wondering if I can create a `PSDrive` like `Env:` for my project specific environment variables, like `$custom:JSenv`, `$custom:root` etc. instead of populating the `Env:` PSDrive.

I tried using `New-PSDrive -Name custom -PSProvider Environment`. I expexceted to see the `custom:` drive. However, in the actual output nothing changed.

Is creating a`Environment` PSDrive the right way to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The `New-PSDrive` cmdlet requires a `Root` parameter.  I was unable to replicate your problem:

```
PS /> $null = New-PSDrive -Name custom -PSProvider Environment -Root ''
PS /> Get-Item -Path custom:
# => environment variables
```

All this really does, however, is give you a different method of calling the `Env:` drive since they use the same provider and the provider does not have a concept of scope.

Answer (score 0):

**No**: To get what you want, **you'd have to implement your own PowerShell [drive] provider** that also implements the [`IContentCmdletProvider` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.icontentcmdletprovider?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), because `$<drive>:<path>` (or `${<drive>:<path>}`) is syntactic sugar - called *namespace notation* - for the following command:
`Get-Content -Path <drive>:<path>`

See the bottom section for more.

---

As for **what you tried**:

While it is possible to define a custom drive based on an existing provider, that drive will invariably reflect that provider's items, without any ability to define your own.

In other words:

```
New-PSDrive -Name custom -PSProvider Environment -Root ''
```

will simply make drive `custom:` an alias of the `env:` drive.
While you could define your custom entries as environment variables, they would show *in addition* to the preexisting ones.

---

#### Implementing a custom PowerShell drive [provider]:

- [Writing your own [drive] provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/provider/writing-a-windows-powershell-provider) requires *compiled* code, so you cannot implement custom drives in PowerShell itself.
- As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0, implementing providers is nontrivial, but [simplifying that is being considered for a future PowerShell *Core* version](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5789).
- However, there are **third-party helper modules** that greatly simplify the process and do allow you to implement custom drives in PowerShell code.
  *Note: I haven't verified that your specific use case can be implemented.*

  - **Simplex**: [PS Gallery link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Simplex) - [source code and documentation](https://github.com/beefarino/simplex) - easy-to-use DSL, but not all features are exposed.
  - **SHiPS**: [PS Gallery link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SHiPS) - [source code and documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/SHiPS) - more complex, but more fully-featured.